# broken dag trying to connect airflow to snowflake

Tags: python, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i've built a POC DAG in python for airflow to execute a function in snowflake but i get this error in airflow's UI:

**Broken DAG: [/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags/snowflake_poc.py] No module named 'snowflake'**

i've read through a lot of documentation floating around and it appears i have everything configured correctly but clearly something's off somewhere.

Here's my python code:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.snowflake_operator import SnowflakeOperator

# These args will get passed on to each operator
# You can override them on a per-task basis during operator initialization
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'snowflake_poc',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='just executing a proc in snowflake',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

sql = "call jme_test_1();"

t1 = SnowflakeOperator(sql = sql,
    warehouse = "DATA_WH",
    database = "DEV_ADS" )
```

i did confirm that airflow has the snowflake_operatory.py file where it should be, just to be safe i even ran **pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python**.  Before anyone asks, yes, i did setup the connection to snowflake in the connection management section in the airflow UI but i'm stuck on this cryptic error.

What am i missing?

Comment: Usually you will get a traceback in airflow_webserver logs. Are you using docker or running airflow locally?

Comment: soon as i can get back on the webserver i'll see if i can find the logs... we used Bitnami's airflow deploy in the azure marketplace to spin up the necessary servers in azure to run it; no docker involved yet.

Comment: i didn't find anything in the webserver logs about my dag or it failing to even try running it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We utilized an Azure Market Place app to setup the airflow server, turns out that server doesn't natively work with snowflake.

We tested this by running this command in Putty

```py
$: python3
>>> import snowflake.connector
```

This threw "No module named 'botocore.docs'"  Which just tells us we're missing a boto3 dependency (had to google botocore and find out that it's part of boto3 package since we're using python3)

Then it was just we needed to install it:

```py
$: sudo pip install --upgrade boto3
```

After that the python code would run but we had to reboot the webserver to get airflow to pick it up.

Comment: that was great, thank you. I got the same error, and it is solved with your answer!!